# Using jcodec SequenceEncoder give ArrayListOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, jcodec

I'm trying to encode video from a few images in my application.

I'm Using jcodec library to implement my task.

This is my code:

```
public class Encoder extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {
    private static final String TAG = "ENCODER";
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<PresentationItem > mData;


    public Encoder(Context context, ArrayList<PresentationItem> mData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {


        File gallery_folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "Test" );

        SequenceEncoder se = null;
        try {
            se = new SequenceEncoder(new File(gallery_folder,
                    "jcodec_enc.mp4"));


            for (int i = 0; i<mData.size(); i++) {

                Bitmap frame = Utils.getBitmap(mData.get(i).getImagePath(), 100, 100);
                se.encodeImage(frame);

              //  publishProgress(i);

            }
            se.finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IO", e);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
    }
}
```

Utils.getBitmap Method:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(String imageFile, int targetW, int targetH)
{
    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);
    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile, bmOptions);
    return b;
}
```

And this is my logcat output:

```
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=13872; index=13940
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at org.jcodec.scale.RgbToYuv420j.rgb2yuv(RgbToYuv420j.java:72)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at org.jcodec.scale.RgbToYuv420j.transform(RgbToYuv420j.java:38)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at org.jcodec.api.SequenceEncoder.encodeNativeFrame(SequenceEncoder.java:72)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at org.jcodec.api.android.SequenceEncoder.encodeImage(SequenceEncoder.java:24)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at com.moblin.huggies.utils.Encoder.doInBackground(Encoder.java:56)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at com.moblin.huggies.utils.Encoder.doInBackground(Encoder.java:22)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-27 07:20:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2743):     ... 5 more
```

The error cause in this line:

```
se.encodeImage(frame);
```

Cant find the reason why this is happening.

Also,the code im using taken from jcode sample.

Comment: indicate line 72 @ `RgbToYuv420j`

Comment: thx for the comment, i added the line to my post.I cant understand why this is falling there

Comment: what is size of `mData`? it's better to change `for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i<mData.size(); i++)`

Comment: the size is more then 10, but i only need 4.